# Creating multiple arrays from users input

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm wondering how to create multiple arrays from the users input. Such that if the user enters a 5, it then makes 5 arrays.

Comment: thats a very vague question. some background/details/code samples would help to understand what you mean.

Comment: Is this homework? *It has the smell of homework about it...* =P If it is, @thehoule64 could you please tag it as such?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java collections for this. That way you no need to worry about the size being entered by the user. I suggest [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be something like a `List`. So, as an example, if a user enters `5`, you'd have a `List<Object[]>` which we could call `l`. Then you could `add` a `new Object[]` for however many times the user entered, which in this case is `5`. This is an addendum to Pangea's answer, which is actually sufficient and includes a really good suggestion to use [Java's Collection Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html). You can read more about `Lists` and an implementation of a `List` called `LinkedList` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you want to create `5 int` arrays of size `7` you could so:

```
int a=7;
int b=5;
int name[][] = new int[b][a];
```